# Changing org-wide sharing settings from Apex

Tags: apex, batch, custom-object, dml, org-wide-defaults

We have an object whose Org-Wide default sharing setting is set to Private.

When an Admin changes a Picklist to Full Access, we have to insert `CustomObject__Share` records for all users, and potentially delete old `__Share` records.

We are doing this in a batch process, but if there are more than 10k users, even if the scope is 1 it fails since we would be inserting more than 10k records.

Is there any way to get around this?  Is it possible to change the Org-Wide default to Read/Write programatically?  Or maybe do it on a profile basis rather than individual users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to have a Group that contains all the users. Then you need to only create one share record that shares with that group.

```
  CustomObject__Share cShare = new CustomObject__Share();
  cShare.ParentId = recordId;
  cShare.UserOrGroupId = groupId; // Group contains all users"
  cShare.AccessLevel = 'Edit';
  cShare.RowCause = Schema.Job__Share.RowCause.Manual;
```

See the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm) for more info on sharing

Comment: I think this would work fine.  There is an "All Internal Users" Public Groups option that means we wouldn't need a trigger if extra users are added.